# How do you send a ctrl-c to a remote machine using Fabric?

Tags: fabric

I am writing a script that execute in sequence some operations on a shell; on a remote machine using Fabric.

At one point, I need to pass ^C (control-C), but I don't know how.

I tried to look on google, and I can see that the hex should be 0003, but I can't figure out how do you actually tell Fabric to read input, as hex/command/ascii, instead than literal string.

I tried various solutions found on the net but neither is specific to Fabric. Whatever I pass to fabric in a command, is always taken as literal and that won't work.

Does anyone know where I can find instructions, to pass keystrokes to simulate ctrl-c ?

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: I'm in the same boat now. have you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [that discussion](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/240):

```
exec_command("\x03")
```

should do the job